# time and space complexity comparison: adding elements of two lists to a dict through loop or dict(zip(s, t))

Tags: python, dictionary, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm new to python and am trying to figure out the concept of time and space complexity. I want to make a dict of two lists, both of the same length. I can do this in the following two ways:

1) by looping over the lists and adding them to the dict:

```
 dictLists = {}
        for i in range(0,len(list1)):
            dictLists[list1[i]] = list2[i]
```

2) by zipping the lists and then making a dict from that:

```
       dictZip = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

To my understanding, the time complexity of the first method should be O(N) where N is the length of the lists. However, I do not know the time complexity for the second option, except the fact that the zip operation itself takes O(1) time complexity.

What would be the difference in time complexity between these two methods? Would there be additional space complexity in the second method due to an extra zip object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have the same time and space complexity. They each have their own individual overheads that aren’t included when talking about complexity, like the `zip` object you mentioned and the `range` object you didn’t, all the function calls that happen in the shadows….

In practice, these aren’t important, so don’t micro-optimize prematurely (“prematurely” here means without having a good reason to expect a performance problem, without encountering one, and without benchmarking) – pick the readable option of `dict(zip(list1, list2))`.

---

P.S.

> except the fact that the zip operation itself takes O(1) time complexity

Creating a `zip` is O(1), but iterating over all of its elements is O(N) on the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Due to python being a dynamic interpreted language and needs to figure out the type of variables in runtime, some variation of the way you implement your code can be noticeably different in run time. For example in the first solution, python would need to figure out the type of "i" in every iteration (can by fixed using cython) so this would kinda slow down the program. With that being said you would not probably notice that with a small number of iteration. As you can see in the testbench the first approach is almost 4X slower.

```
import time
list1 = [x for x in range(1000000)]
list2 = [x for x in range(1000000)]

dictLists = dict()
l = len(list1)

s = time.time()
for i in range(0, l):
    dictLists[list1[i]] = list2[i]
print(f"Time: {time.time()-s}")
# 0.39275574684143066

dictLists = dict()
s = time.time()

dictZip = dict(zip(list1,list2))
print(f"Time: {time.time()-s}")
# 0.09296393394470215
```